# Change bookmark in selenium

Tags: c#, selenium

How to change bookmark in my test? My case:

- Navigate
- Wait until page is loaded
- Click on button
- New bookmark is created
- Wait until new page is loaded (in new bookmark)
- Do things...

  ```
  var wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
  driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://MyPage");
  wait.Until(drv => drv.FindElement(By.XPath(".//*[@id='ui-id-1']")));
  Thread.Sleep(1000);
  driver.FindElement(By.Id("AddNewRecord")).Click();
  Console.WriteLine(driver.Url);
  wait.Until(drv => drv.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[contains(text(), 'Country')]")));
  driver.FindElement(By.Name("Country")).Click();
  ```

Problem: Driver is still watching on first bookmark and always timeout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ugh... Got it!

```
driver.SwitchTo().Window(driver.WindowHandles[1]);
```